# Python module installation error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, unix, installation, debian

I am on Debian Squeeze, and I want to install the module *[igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/)*. So, I am going through all the [steps](http://igraph.wikidot.com/installing-python-igraph-on-linux), but when i try doing

```
python setup.py build
```

I get error that says:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

But, on the beginning of the terminal message I get errors like these:

```
In file included from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/arpackobject.h:26:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Here is the full output of the terminal:

```
# python setup.py build
Include path: /usr/local/include/igraph
Library path: /usr/local/lib
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'igraph._igraph' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/arpackobject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/arpackobject.o
In file included from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/arpackobject.h:26:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/arpackobject.h:28,
                 from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/graphobject.h:28:26: error: structmember.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/graphobject.h:29,
                 from src/arpackobject.h:28,
                 from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/common.h:68: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/common.h:69: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from src/arpackobject.h:28,
                 from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/graphobject.h:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘igraphmodule_GraphType’
src/graphobject.h:39: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
src/graphobject.h:53: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:55: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘visitproc’
src/graphobject.h:57: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/graphobject.h:57: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/graphobject.h:58: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:59: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:61: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:62: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:63: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:64: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:65: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:66: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:67: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:68: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:69: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:70: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:71: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:72: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:73: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:74: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:75: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:76: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:78: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:79: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:80: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:81: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:82: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:83: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:84: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:85: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:86: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:87: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:88: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:89: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:90: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:91: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:92: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:93: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:94: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:95: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:96: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:97: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:98: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:99: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:101: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:102: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:103: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:104: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:105: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:106: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:107: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:108: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:109: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:110: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:111: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:112: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:113: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:114: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:115: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:116: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:117: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:118: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:119: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:120: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:121: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:122: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:123: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:124: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:125: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:126: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:127: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:128: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:129: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:131: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:132: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:133: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:134: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:135: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:136: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:137: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:138: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:139: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:140: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:141: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:142: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:144: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:145: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:146: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:147: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:149: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:151: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:152: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:153: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:154: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:155: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:156: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:157: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:158: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:159: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:160: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:161: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:162: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:163: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:164: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:166: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:167: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:168: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:169: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:170: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:171: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:172: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:175: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:176: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/graphobject.h:176: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/graphobject.h:177: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:178: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:179: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:181: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:182: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:184: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:185: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:186: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:187: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:188: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:189: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:190: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:192: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:193: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:195: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:196: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:197: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:198: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:200: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:201: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:202: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:203: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:204: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:205: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:206: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:207: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:209: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:210: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:211: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:212: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:213: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:214: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from src/arpackobject.h:28,
                 from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/graphobject.h:215: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:216: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:217: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:218: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:219: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:221: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:223: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/graphobject.h:224: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from src/arpackobject.c:23:
src/arpackobject.h:34: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsType’
src/arpackobject.h:41: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
src/arpackobject.h:46: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.h:50: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.h:51: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.h:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from src/arpackobject.c:25:
src/error.h:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/error.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from src/arpackobject.c:26:
src/py2compat.h:80: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.c:28: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.c:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.c:43: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.c: In function ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptions_dealloc’:
src/arpackobject.c:61: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyObject_Del’
src/arpackobject.c:61: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/arpackobject.c:61: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/arpackobject.c:61: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/arpackobject.c:61: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
src/arpackobject.c: At top level:
src/arpackobject.c:67: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.c:123: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/arpackobject.c: In function ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptions_setattr’:
src/arpackobject.c:124: error: ‘value’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/arpackobject.c:125: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyErr_SetString’
src/arpackobject.c:125: error: ‘PyExc_TypeError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/arpackobject.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’
src/arpackobject.c:130: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyInt_Check’
src/arpackobject.c:131: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyInt_AsLong’
src/arpackobject.c:133: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:135: error: ‘PyExc_ValueError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/arpackobject.c:144: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:145: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyFloat_Check’
src/arpackobject.c:146: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:146: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyFloat_AsDouble’
src/arpackobject.c:152: error: ‘PyExc_AttributeError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/arpackobject.c: In function ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptions_get’:
src/arpackobject.c:162: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:162: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:163: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:163: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:164: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:164: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:165: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:165: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:166: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:166: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:167: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:168: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c:168: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params’
src/arpackobject.c:170: error: ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsObject’ has no member named ‘params_out’
src/arpackobject.c: At top level:
src/arpackobject.c:179: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/arpackobject.c:191: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptions_methods’
src/arpackobject.c:204: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptions_getseters’
src/arpackobject.c:215: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘igraphmodule_ARPACKOptionsType’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Python header files are in the `python-dev` package, which includes:

> Header files, a static library and development tools for building Python modules, extending the Python interpreter or embedding Python in applications.

Try:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

That should do the trick. You can also download it [from here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-dev).

**EDIT**

try the following:

```
apt-get install python-devel
or
apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

Comment: I already have installed python-dev. # apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. And it is still the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It can't find both of the packages. For python-devel it says: E: Unable to locate package python-devel, and for python2.7-dev it gives me two errors: E: Unable to locate package python2.7-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7-dev'. What should I do now?

Comment: if your version is 2.7 you can download it from [here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python2.7-dev)

Comment: It was conflict between versions of Python (I have 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7). I sorted out the problem by adjusting the right versions. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 3):

The missing file is in the package python-dev on a debian system. Install it and you're fine.

Comment: I have installed python-dev already, but that didn't solve my problem. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to install the following package then.

```
python-all-dev
```

Comment: Not found with `yum`