# Error greenlet docker build

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, gevent, greenlets

everything good? I have a problem using docker build. This application has already been mounted on 2 other machines but every time this error occurs. Does anyone know what I should do to fix it. I have a windows 10 and im using Docker Toolbox.

I tried this answer here from the site without success:

[Python module installation error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720578/python-module-installation-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)

I followed the docking tutorial from docker's own website:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#define-the-project-components

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN  python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
ADD . /code/
```

Error log:

```
PS C:\Users\ThinkPad\Documents\ChatBot> docker build -t backend .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  209.5MB
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3
 ---> ce54ff8f2af6
Step 2/9 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5cefadc9e069
Step 3/9 : RUN mkdir /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1dd0287bc4ba
Step 4/9 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3790083599e1
Step 5/9 : RUN pip3 install virtualenv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ddc61851cc43
Step 6/9 : RUN virtualenv /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa9028959057
Step 7/9 : ADD requirements.txt /code/
 ---> a4b2b341f4f6
Step 8/9 : RUN  python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
 ---> Running in fe0b99a3ecf4
Requirement already satisfied: pip==10.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (10.0.1)
Collecting amqp==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/4a/8c45a882d842678963516ebd9cf584a4ded51af719234c3b696c2e884c60/amqp-2.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48kB)
Collecting billiard==3.5.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/55/76f4e786141b7174926cdffa7a155aeea316b729118fb48ec548f3c6754f/billiard-3.5.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (89kB)
Collecting celery==4.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/9b/88ef5cc7edf5d43215f383ae0a2b1cdeb33f5f07886386c7e4691b2eba0c/celery-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (400kB)
Collecting Django==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/2a/3a0ec97b18d6e8d295142228f03604ac78ea6de05cf9bc3773a74f0b58bb/Django-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
Collecting django-cors-headers==2.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/97/40b519badff93449706cd2cab3f328e1898e627bb218e3429c5581ad1932/django_cors_headers-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-notifs==2.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/30/8b9b90d3aa47b3b50046eb202727730a6d9ba9b4bc45478ba35466e7662c/django-notifs-2.6.0.tar.gz
Collecting django-templated-mail==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/a8/9619c9a6fbe784c5d9c31283aeb2dd16c1f16902485b7c3f578b39ecd21b/django_templated_mail-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting djangorestframework==3.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/0f/70957d583a9040c902b22dfab88323c1be61266eaddb1b3463a401004856/djangorestframework-3.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
Collecting djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/cf/b3932ad3261d6332284152a00c3e3a275a653692d318acc6b2e9cf6a1ce3/djangorestframework_jwt-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whlCollecting djoser==1.1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/cf/d985a0a453a02c018a68ea69de6c9482bbb345ec85037355601a0023525f/djoser-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gevent==1.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/92/b111f76e54d2be11375b47b213b56687214f258fd9dae703546d30b837be/gevent-1.2.2.tar.gz (3.1MB)
Collecting greenlet==0.4.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/76/82af375d98724054b7e273b5d9369346937324f9bcc20980b45b068ef0b0/greenlet-0.4.12.tar.gz (57kB)
Collecting kombu==4.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/a4/5d16954803224a1e451713293c2a028614099f5538cf626e1fdd7b438c86/kombu-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181kB)
Collecting pika==0.11.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/b4/0ada6918ac79ce4d8d45d0ba436ee21a1ef685047fb1dde4d2de0178b327/pika-0.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (107kB)
Collecting PyJWT==1.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/8f/19c302aa9a391dd1fbd249362b749021b88d40fb59af0363939a2250afed/PyJWT-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz==2017.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/7f/e7d1acbd433b929168a4fb4182a2ff3c33653717195a26c1de099ad1ef29/pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (511kB)
Collecting simplejson==3.13.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/3f/3a16847fe5c010110a8f54dd8fe7b091b4e22922def374fe1cce9c1cb7e9/simplejson-3.13.2.tar.gz (79kB)
Collecting six==1.11.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting uwsgi==2.0.15 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/0a/45e5aa80dc135889594bb371c082d20fb7ee7303b174874c996888cc8511/uwsgi-2.0.15.tar.gz (795kB)
Collecting vine==1.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/50/5b1ebe42843c19f35edb15022ecae339fbec6db5b241a7a13c924dabf2a3/vine-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.7.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/09/4991fcd9a8f4bea1ee3948e1729fa17c184d25bd10809bacc143626361b9/psycopg2-binary-2.7.4.tar.gz (426kB)
Collecting ptvsd==3.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/44/6dedb2ef160c72c46c4575885bb9d2d6c464202915c14312d02fad0b9c70/ptvsd-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59kB)
Installing collected packages: vine, amqp, billiard, pytz, kombu, celery, Django, django-cors-headers, pika, six, django-notifs, django-templated-mail, djangorestframework, PyJWT, djangorestframework-jwt, djoser, greenlet, gevent, simplejson, uwsgi, psycopg2-binary, ptvsd
  Running setup.py install for django-notifs: started
    Running setup.py install for django-notifs: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for greenlet: started
    Running setup.py install for greenlet: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-g5y1o81k/greenlet/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-mz7pfy5s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/greenlet.o
    greenlet.c: In function ‘g_switchstack’:
    greenlet.c:463:29: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       current->exc_type = tstate->exc_type;
                                 ^~
    greenlet.c:464:30: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       current->exc_value = tstate->exc_value;
                                  ^~
    greenlet.c:465:34: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       current->exc_traceback = tstate->exc_traceback;
                                      ^~
    greenlet.c:485:9: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = target->exc_type;
             ^~
    greenlet.c:487:9: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = target->exc_value;
             ^~
    greenlet.c:489:9: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = target->exc_traceback;
             ^~
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-g5y1o81k/greenlet/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-mz7pfy5s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-g5y1o81k/greenlet/
The command '/bin/sh -c python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to a cython incompatability issue with python 3.7 (https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1978).

Modify your image name as `FROM python:3.6-stretch` and this should work fine

Answer (score 18):

Although the solution of ClumsyPuffin works well it uses a heavier distribution.
I just fixed this issue by adding the following line in the Dockerfile before installing the requirements.

`RUN apk add build-base`

> build-base is a meta-package that will install the GCC, libc-dev and
> binutils packages (amongst others).
> https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/GCC

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This solution resolved my issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works also in my flask environment

Comment: works for flask based app containerization... I am using Mac M1

Comment: If you have a problem with flask ```Flask-SQLAlchemy``` then this solution will help you.